# How to position these divs in my flexbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have no idea why this has been so difficult but the flex box aspect is complicating things. I'm trying to achieve this, responsively -

[image]

I've followed various flex tutorials to no avail. My HTML/css:

```
<div class="frame">
                <div id = "topBar">

                </div>
                <div id = "leftCol">

                </div>
                <div id = "rightCol">

                </div>
                <div id = "center">
                    <span>
                            </span>
                </div>
                <div id = "bottomCol">

                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .frame {
        position: fixed;
        display: none;
        z-index: 10000;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: none;
        height: 100vh;
        padding: 3rem;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        bottom: 0;
        text-align: center;
        // grid-template-columns: 15% 70% 15%;
        // grid-template-rows: 15% 70% 15%;
    }

#topBar {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    float: center;
    width: 100%;

}

#bottomCol {
        align-self: flex-end;
        width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
}
#bottomCol p {

    transform: rotate(0deg);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    padding-right: 6px;
}
#leftCol {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    position: relative;

}

#leftCol > h2, p{
     transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
#rightCol {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.scrollBar {
    width: 2px;
    height: 55px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    top: 15px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#center {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    bottom: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

This results in nothing of what I need. How can I do this?

Comment: I think you need to wrap the three divs in the middle in a root div first, so that you can split the screen horizontally between three divs. Then inside this root div, just place the top, center, and bottom divs on top of each other.

Comment: That's a good way, though there are definitely others. This would be a lot more straightforward in a grid I'd say. That's not really a good [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) though. A simpler one would make the answer easier.

Comment: @Yishmeray fair enough - see the updated min example

Comment: @AhmedHammad see the updated minimal html.. Can you provide an answer with css?

Comment: I don't have time to write it, but I am pretty sure it'll work with flex this way - main box is flex-direction: column and flex-wrap: wrap. First div on the left is width (say) 10%, height 100%; next three divs are all width: 80% (you can subtract gutter if you like). Then their heights are (say) 10%, 80%, 10%. Last div on the right is again width: 10% and height 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox was also difficult at the begging for me, allow me to break it down and try to explain your flexbox problem. And probably this will make things more clear. 
Flexbox is one direction and works based on containers to define that direction.

```css
  .page-container{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;
      border:solid 5px red;
      padding: 3rem;
      justify-content:strech;
      align-items:strech;
      min-height: 100vh;
   }
.page-element {
  margin: 0 1rem 0 1rem;
   border:solid 1px;
 }
.left-container{
  flex: 0 1 350px;
  margin-left:0;
}
.center-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex:1;
}
.right-container{
  flex: 0 1 350px;
  margin-right:0;
}

.top-container{
  flex: 0 1 150px;
  border:solid 1px;
 }
.middle-container{
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}
.bottom-container{
  flex: 0 1 150px;
  border:solid 1px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="page-element left-container">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="page-element center-container">
    <div class="top-container">
      top
    </div>
    <div class="middle-container">
      center
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-container">
      bottom
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="page-element right-container">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Once you have the containers you can set the **directions** in our CSS

So you need to define 1st your first 3 columns. Although, it may sound odd it is one row in flexbox and items will be one next to the other 
therefore **page-container** needs to be `flex-direction:row`

The other tricky one is the `center-container` since it has 3 sections there. In flexbox this is one column, therefore `flex-direction` is `column`.

Hope this helps and explains it.

Answer (score 2):

This layout can be done easy with Grid Layout, this in an example taking in account what you need:

In the #page selector you set how will be the layout and in the next selectors, you set how every grid area will be called:

```css
#page {
        display: grid;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        grid-template-areas:
          "leftCol topBar rightCol"
          "leftCol center rightCol"
          "leftCol bottomCol rightCol";
        grid-template-rows: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
      }

      #topBar {
        grid-area: topBar;
        background-color: #ffa08c;
      }

      #leftCol {
        grid-area: leftCol;
        background-color: #8ca0ff;
      }

      #rightCol {
        grid-area: rightCol;
        background-color: #ffff64;
      }

      #center {
        grid-area: center;
        background-color: #8cffa0;
      }

      #bottomCol {
        grid-area: bottomCol;
        background-color: #ff8c8c;
      }
```

```html
<div id="page">
      <div id="topBar">
        <h2>01-02-2020</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="leftCol">
        <h1>'-'</h1>
        <h2>lightbulbs</h2>
      </div>
      <div id="rightCol">
        <p>[</p>
        <div class="scrollBar"></div>
        <p>]</p>
      </div>
      <div id="center">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae alias, dolore, deleniti sed
          explicabo natus reprehenderit quae iure nostrum aliquam illo nihil velit totam corrupti,
          debitis reiciendis quibusdam nam vel!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="bottomCol">
        <p id="aggregate" style="transform: rotate(0deg);">[aggregate]</p>
        <p id="daily" style="transform: rotate(0deg);">daily</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Grid Layout is not supported in IE10 and IE11 if I recall correctly

Comment: thats right, this is the browser support https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Comment: pretty sure the OP wants flex, but I agree grid should do this nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Flex can only go in one direction either vertically or horizontally.

From the picture we can determine that the layout will go horizontally, However for the middle bit it will go vertically.

So we have to nest those middle elements in another flex container.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body * {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

[container] {
    height: 100vh;
}

[container], [nested] {
    display: flex;
}

[container]>div {
    margin: 5px;
}

[nested] {
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

[nested]>div:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div container>
  <div></div>
  <div nested>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

---

If changing the html isn't an option then there's one more solution but you'll have to define a height for the container.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body * {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

[container] {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

[container]>div {
  margin: 5px;
}

[container]>div:first-child,
[container]>div:last-child {
  height: 100%;
}

[container]>div:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div container>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```